# Creating an object in a proper format

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, object

I am trying to create an object in a particular format and having some trouble with getting the data I need.

This is my function:

```
arr.forEach(headers => {
    let heads = headers.replace(/_/g, ' ');
    const metrics = {
        'cht': {
            headers: {
                'name': heads
            }
        }
    }
    console.log(metrics);
});
```

My result is:

```
{cht: {headers: {name: "Hello World"}}}
```

Expected Result:

```
{cht: {Hello_World: {name: "Hello World"}}}
```

Why isn't the value `headers` (to cut) getting replaced in my object? I need headers to be `Hello_World`.

Comment: What do you mean by `replaced`? You're not doing anything _to_ the `headers`.

Comment: reverse replace, src to des: `headers.replace(/ /g, '_')`

Comment: I did that. but the value `headers` is still the same

Comment: I added an expected result

Comment: Just put a bracket around `headers` like: `'cht': { [headers]: { 'name': heads } }`

Comment: @norbertpy If you want to add an answer with that info, I can remove mine.

Comment: @norbertpy, Is there a way for me to use `metrics` outside of the forEach loop?

Comment: If you use `arr.map` instead of `arr.forEach` and add a `return metrics` then you'll get an array of `metrics` back. Otherwise you need to define an array outside of `forEach` and just do `result.push(metrics)` within the function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you create an object, the property keys (what's to the left of the :) are normally not treated as variables, they are used as names, exactly as they're typed.

In newer versions of Javascript (ECMAScript 6 on), you can put brackets around the name so that the variable value itself is used as a property key.

```
arr.forEach(headers => {
    let heads = headers.replace(/_/g, ' ');
    const metrics = {
        cht: {
            [headers]: heads
        }
    }
    console.log(metrics);
});
```

Comment: key should be capitalized as OP expected:
`{cht: {Hello_World: {name: "Hello World"}}}`

Comment: Is there a way for me to use `metrics` outside of the forEach loop?

Comment: @noob Something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=oIwhV52svl

Answer (score 1):

You have it backwards, the first parameter in replace is the RegExp to find, the second parameter is what to replace it with. It should be `headers.replace(/ /g, '_')`.

```
arr.forEach(headers => {
    const newHeader = headers.replace(/ /g, '_');
    const metrics = {
        cht: {
            [newHeader]: {
               name: headers
            }
        }
    };
    console.log(metrics);
});
```

Comment: I did that. but the value headers is still the same

Comment: I added an expected result

Comment: Is your input `['Hello World']` or `['Hello_World']`?

Answer (score 0):

The value you are assigning as the replaced 'headers' you've set as the var 'heads.'

You're then assigning it as the value for the property 'name'.
Did you mean to set it as the property for headers instead?:

```
let heads = headers.replace(/_/g, ' ');
    const metrics = {
        'cht': {
            headers: {
                heads: 'someValue'
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I added an expected result

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're providing `headers = 'Hello World'`. `headers` *is* being replaced.

Your replace pattern is looking for a literal `_` to be replaced with a whitespace character. [`String.prototype.replace(pattern, replacement)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace).

But it sounds like you're trying to do the opposite.

`replace(/\s/g, '_')` or simply `replace(' ', '_')` would result in `'Hello_World'`.

Comment: `headers = 'Hello_World'` and `heads = headers.replace(/_/g, ' ');` which makes `head=Hello World`

Comment: I see the question has been updated. My answer no longer applies. I'd say @ThisIsNoZaku has the correct answer with the new context provided in the question.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following

```
headers.split(" ").join("_");
```

OR

```
headers.replace(/ /g, '_')
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `split` and `map` to get expected output.

```js
const capitalize = (str) => `${str.charAt(0).toUpperCase()}${str.slice(1)}`;
const normalization = (name = "") => {
  if (!name) return name;
  return name.split(/\s+/).map(capitalize).join("_");
};
const transform = (arr) => {
  arr.forEach((headers = "") => {
    let heads = normalization(headers);
    const metrics = {
      cht: {
        [heads]: {name: headers}
      },
    };
    console.log(metrics);
  });
};

const arr = ["hello world", "test    some  thing"];

transform(arr);
```